# Is there a way I can choose not to award bounty?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

I understand the reputation I paid for bounty is not coming back anyway, and I think this is reasonable to prevent people from starting bounty without careful consideration. It is also okay to make it default to award half the bounty to the highest vote answer to prevent the starter of the bounty forgot to choose and award. However, is there a way I can choose not to award bounty to any answer?

This is needed especially when I start a bounty because the current answer is bad and hope to get a new answer by raising attention. When no new answer is made after the bounty, I am now forced to give the bounty to the only poor answer which is exactly why I need to start the bounty! Actually I am even willing to pay another bounty to prevent that from happening!

Comment: Only answers added after the bounty was started can be auto-awarded.

Comment: BTW, since you don't seem to be pingable on the question, I've added a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If none of your answers at the end of the bounty period(7 days+grace period) has the **minimum required 2 votes** and **you haven't selected an answer** then the bounty will not be awarded to anyone.

If at all any of your answers have more than two votes (*may have have something relevant to the question*) but doesn't answer your question in anyway then you may first ask the user who answered to improve the answer as per requirement. And later down-vote if not done.

> If you feel the answer is not an answer to your question, flag it as
>   "not an answer".

Read through [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

From the [What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) page :

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or
>   more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the
>   oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria,
>   no bounty is awarded to anyone.

Comment: Note that *If you feel the answer is not an answer to your question, flag it as "not an answer".* is a bit misleading. You can only flag an answer if it doesn't answer any question. As soon as an answer shows an attempt at answering flags are likely to be disputed if not declined.

Comment: Your first paragraph should contain "If non of the answers *posted after the bounty started* (..)", the reason is given in the last quote block.